ECDLP and binary quadratic forms
Suppose $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has prime order $q$, and $E$ has some
model $E: y^2 = x^3 + a_4x + a_6$.
We can vary small $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ at random until $r = t\cdot q-1$ is prime.
Let $n = -a_6\cdot r^2$.  Then we will eventually have the size of the group of binary quadratic forms of discriminant $-4n$ will be divisible by $q$.  I forget why this works (I think it is fairly straightforward).
Since all groups of fixed prime order are isomorphic, this means in theory we have an injective homomorphism:
$\psi: E(\mathbb{F}_p) \rightarrow \operatorname{Cl}(-4n)$,
embedding the group of $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ of order $q$ in the group of binary quadratic forms with discriminant $-4n$.
If this homomorphism could be efficiently computed, it would break ECDLP, since we have a subexponential algorithm for class group DLP which will not withstand the group sizes used in EC cryptography in practice.  The problem would be reduced to finding a discriminant with an appropriate class number, as outlined above.
Just to give an example:
Let $E: y^2 = x^3 - 7$ (so $a_6 = -7$).
Let $p = 1000000000039$.
Then $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) = 999998130067$ (prime), so we have
$q = 999998130067$.
Then $n = 9071966071966865604521410447 = -a_6 \cdot r^2$, where
$r = t\cdot q - 1 = 36 \cdot 999998130067 - 1$
and we have the size of the group of binary quadratic forms of discriminant $-4n$ equals $36q$, therefore we have our embedding.
The question is, can $\psi$ be efficiently computed?
(Note:  To compute the above class number I used the pari-gp function qfbclassno, I hope I am not mistaken in the group size - it is not the same group we get for the corresponding number field.)

One possible comment is "why would embedding $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ in $\operatorname{Cl}(-4n)$ be any easier than embedding it in $Z/qZ$?".  This might be why I abandoned the idea before... but nevertheless the more different groups we get... eventually might hit one with a $\psi$ that is efficient to compute.
